# javascript button selected onload

Tags: javascript, button, onload

an anyone tell how can i make a button on page onload.As i have a login page and i want to make the login button selected onload and when i press eneter the onclick of button should be called.
I want to do this in chorme.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use the `focus` function to set the focus the your button

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
  window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('YourButtonId').focus();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know f it's different for chrome, but while the user is editing any form the enter button should automatically click the Submit button

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net try asp panel's default button property to ur button and thats it....